# Thickness of underline

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to control the thickness of an underline, however, it seems its just one huge horizontal line that does not conform to the text. How can I get the text to underline as the same thickness of the text:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.title {

border-bottom: 2px solid red;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ??? you want an underline that is a thick as the text size? So when you have for example a font-size of 14 pixel you want the underline also 14 pixel?

Comment: What's wrong with using `text-decoration:underline;`?

Comment: are you talking about the horizontal width or thickness of the line?

Comment: @Simon, I am not fond of the 1px line.

Comment: @user1451890 ok, just want to make sure, because most of the answers tell you how to limit the width ;)

Answer (score 3):

The 'border-bottom' style is being added to the 'div' tag. Because by defult 'divs' are set to 'display: block;' the width of the div is 100%. To solve this, add another tag surrounding the text and give the class to that tag.

For Example: `<div><span class="title">test</span></div>`

New Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.title {

border-bottom: 2px solid red;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><span class="title">test</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

you just have to insert `display:inline-block;` in your css or `float` the element;

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you're using a `border`, not an underline. The border extends the full length of the element, which for a `div` is `width: 100%` by default.

To change that you should limit the width of the `div` explicitly, or by using `float` or changing its `display`.

Using `width`:

```
div {
    width: 10em; /* or whatever... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w3sVP/).

Using `float`:

```
div {
    float: left; /* or 'right' */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w3sVP/1/).

Using `display`:

```
div {
    display: inline-block; /* or 'inline' */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w3sVP/2).

Of course, given that you effectively want the underline to be below the text and, presumably, serve to 'underline' the text (see the problem with the demo, using a defined width if the [text is longer than the defined width](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w3sVP/3/)), it'd be easier to simply use an in-line element, such as a [`span`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w3sVP/4/) for this, rather than a `div`, since its default behaviour is the same behaviour that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `div` to a `span`.

`span` is good for short pieces of text on a single line.

See here:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fwZgs/)

Comment: The underline disappears then. (IE 7)

Comment: Ahh -- sorry. Works in Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `em` instead of `px`, the border adopts the font size.

```
span {
    font-size:5em;
    border: solid black;
    border-width:0 0 0.1em;
}​
```

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5K9CN/).

Comment: I am guessing that theres not an IE7 friendly method?

Comment: Well, this should work in IE7. I will check that, just booting my windows can … ;)

Comment: Checked. Works fine in IE7. Do you experience any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for IE7 there is only method to make this work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
h1 {
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
display: inline;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div><h1>Hello, world</h1></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding: margin: auto. 
This should scale the line according the length of the text